# glob syntax to match a files with any extension or no extension

Tags: php, glob, php-5.6

I'd like to search for "amazon" in the folder and find anything ("amazon.jpg", "amazon.gif", "amazon")

But if I do this:

```
glob($path . 'amazon*');
```

It will also find "amazon-prime" which I don't want. If on the other end I do

```
glob($path . 'amazon.*');
```

Then it will not pick up "amazon-prime", which is what I want, but it also won't pick up "amazon" (no extension) which I need to know if it exists.

Anyone has a way of finding a file with any extension, including no extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With deep dive to [`glob` man page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#refsect1-function.glob-parameters):

```
print_r(glob('./{amazon\.*,amazon}', GLOB_BRACE));
```

Less "amazing":

```
print_r(array_merge(
    glob('./amazon\.*'),
    glob('./amazon')
));
```

Comment: Ah nice! I don't know how I didn't think about using braces, thanks friend!